# How can I set time limit on get_file_contents in PHP?

Tags: php

At times the get_file_contents takes too long and that hangs the entire script. Is there any way of setting a time out limit on get_file_contents, without modifying the maximum execution time of the script?

## Edit:

Its taking long because the file does not exist. I am getting "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!" error. But it takes forever.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Seems to be possible in PHP > 5.2.1 by creating a context with the [timeout option](http://de.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).

Slightly amended example from the manual page:

```
<?php

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'timeout' => 120 
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/get.php', false, $context);

?>
```

Comment: +1 : I love it when people suggest to use streams *(which are one of the great things of PHP that almost noone knows about ;-( )*

Comment: If the specified time limit will be reached the function will return `FALSE`? So I will not be able to distinguish time out error from all others?

Comment: Does this timeout specify the maximum duration of the entire request, start to end? Or is it the maximum time allowed to pass between two successive bytes being received?

Comment: @Thomas I do not know; I have little experience with it. (It might be worth a separate question, or an experiment using some sort of throttling mechanism)

Answer (score 1):

you count use `ini_set` and set `"default_socket_timeout"` before using `file_get_contents` and then restore the old value after it - if would affect some other parts of your code...